# Why is my LOGGING setting changed automatically?

Tags: django-logging

On ubuntu I have a python environment
In Django settings.py I have following

```
MIDDLEWARE = [
    'django.middleware.security.SecurityMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.sessions.middleware.SessionMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.csrf.CsrfViewMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.auth.middleware.AuthenticationMiddleware',
    'django.contrib.messages.middleware.MessageMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.clickjacking.XFrameOptionsMiddleware',
    'corsheaders.middleware.CorsMiddleware',
    'django.middleware.common.CommonMiddleware',
    'core.middleware.audit.AuditMiddleware',
    'silk.middleware.SilkyMiddleware'
]

LOGGING = {
    'version': 1,
    'disable_existing_loggers': False,
    'handlers': {
        'console': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'logging.StreamHandler',
        },
        'logfile': {
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'class': 'logging.FileHandler',
            'filename': '/var/log/django.log',
        }
    },
    'root': {
        'handlers': ['console', 'logfile'],
        'level': 'DEBUG',
    },
    'loggers': {
        'django': {
            'handlers': ['console', 'logfile'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'propagate': True
        },
        'django.db.backends': {
            'handlers': ['console', 'logfile'],
            'level': 'DEBUG',
            'propagate': True
        },
    },
}
```

**DEBUG** is set to True

I was debugging why logger is not working. I got to know somewhere before dictConfig my Logging setting is being changed to

```
{'version': 1,
'disable_existing_loggers': False, 
'formatters': {'verbose': {'format': '%(asctime)s [%(process)d] [%(levelname)s] pathname=%(pathname)s lineno=%(lineno)s funcname=%(funcName)s %(message)s', 'datefmt': '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'}, 'simple': {'format': '%(levelname)s %(message)s'}}, 
'handlers': {'null': {'level': 'DEBUG', 'class': 'logging.NullHandler'}, 'console': {'level': 'DEBUG', 'class': 'logging.StreamHandler', 'formatter': 'verbose'}}, 
'loggers': {'testlogger': {'handlers': ['console'], 'level': 'INFO'}}
```

Why is this info changed? How do I fix it. I'm using Django 3.1 with VSCode

When I am navigating through Admin site I want to see queries on console when DEBUG is True